# How to create sortable table rows using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to create a `.sortable`table using jQuery. The `fixWidthHelper` class preserves the table column widths. (I've removed some of the HTML)

**Table HTML:**

```
<table class = "table table-bordered" >
           hr content here...
    <tbody id = "field_wrapper">
            <tr>
              <td id = "move">...</td>
              <td id = "move">...</td>       
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

**jQuery:**

```
    $(function (sort) {
    sortable_tables.sorting_field_table();

});

var sortable_tables =
{
    sorting_field_table: function(sort)
    {
        $('#field_wrapper').sortable({
        placeholder: "drop",
        helper: sortable_tables.fixWidthHelper
        }).disableSelection();
    }
    fixWidthHelper: function(e, ui) {
        ui.children().each(function(sort) {
            $(this).width($(this).width()); 
        });
        return ui;
    }
});
```

**CSS:**

```
#move{ margin-left: 0px; padding-right:10px; cursor: move;}
.drop { 
    outline: thin dashed #CCC !important;
    background-color:#CCC;
    width:100%;
    }
```

Comment: `$(function (sort) {...});` simply makes `sort` an alias for `jQuery` within the block.  The next `function(sort)` expects a parameter, and the last `function(sort)` makes `sort` equivalent to the index of each `ui.children()`.  None of these functions refer to the `sort` parameter.  We'll need to see more code.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I've updated my question to include the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got it it working!

**jQuery:**

```
$(function() {
  $( "#field_wrapper" ).sortable({
    placeholder: "drop"
  });
  $( "#field_wrapper" ).disableSelection();
});
```

Comment: Note: you need both the following jQuery links for it to work: `<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script> <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

The first block of your code is just defining a function on `document.ready` but it is not called anywhere.

Also, I don't see anything here that is actually performing any sorting.

Comment: This is just the function. It is within the document.ready call. The sorting applies to #field-wrapper.sortable

Comment: `$(function(...)` is shorthand for `$( document ).ready()`.  See https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/.  So this answer is somewhat correct, although a function isn't actually being defined within the block.